# Оставить ссылки из импортируемого контента другого сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла потребность в импортировании содержимого с другого сайта. На сервере другого сайта разрешил получение контента моему сайту, через `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, чтобы стало возможным получать контент оттуда. У себя на странице сделал следующее:

```
<header class="header">
    <link rel="import" href="http://стороннийсайт/" />    
</header>
```

Сам скрипт, который дописывает полученный контент со стороннего сайта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
        var content = link.import;
        if (content != null) {
            var el = content.querySelector('.header');
            document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Да, с другого сайта я беру хидер, в котором лежит меню с несколькими ссылками. Что в полученном результате меня не устраивает:

1. Изображение с полученного контента не подтягивается
2. Ссылки встраиваемого контента изменяются

Соответственно, у меня два вопроса:

1. **Как подгрузить изображение с другого сайта на свой?**
2. **Как сделать правильную ссылку?**

Пояснения по второму вопросу:

Если зайти на страницу стороннего сайта, то у него ссылки следующего формата:

> [http://стороннийсайт/other/first](http://%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/other/first)
>   [http://стороннийсайт/other/two](http://%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/other/two)
>   [http://стороннийсайт/about](http://%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/about)

После того, как я получаю содержимое со стороннего сайта и встраиваю в свой, ссылки изменяются:

> [http://мойсайт/other/first](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/other/first)
>   [http://мойсайт/other/two](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/other/two)
>   [http://мойсайт/about](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/about)

Мне нужно, чтобы ссылки не изменялись, а оставались такими же, как на стороннем сайте.

Comment: Скорее всего ссылки которые пытаетесь добыть заданы через относительный путь. Тут только вручную дописывать путь, учитывая то, что вы знаете адрес откуда вы берете, не должно составлять проблемы (или я что-то не так понял)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, я конечно могу пройтись по полученному контенту и изменить путь на тот, который мне нужен, но я думаю, что тут можно не изобретать велосипед, а что-то куда-то дописать и будет мне счастье. А что с картинкой?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, хотя, видимо без велосипеда не обойтись, Вы правы, относительный путь указан. Вот блин

Comment: Я ошибся и удалил коммент, попробую поколдовать локально

Comment: Попробовал локально, через template, если путь указан верно (относительно того от куда ты берешь) то картинка загрузилась. Не знаю насколько подходит вариант такой (взято из https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/ Including templates)

Comment: У меня получилось что так, что так вставить, напрямую по id выдернуть из страницы элемент и вставить в страницу. Это не имеет роли. Проблема только в относительных путях, которые надо заменить

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, в данный момент вот что делаю: `var arr = el.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {...}` немного криво пока, но думаю, что скоро получится.

Comment: можешь forEach использовать (гораздо удобнее), и устанавливать атрибут по `(lnk) => lnk.setAttribute('href', 'тут проще через regExp сделать')`. Получить можно по `lnk.getAttribute('href')`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а Вы не могли бы мне немного помочь, ну ответ к примеру написать, пока я бегаю в цикле и меняю аттрибуты )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт получения контента сайта необходимо дополнить следующим кодом:

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');

// Clone the <template> in the import.
var template = link.import.getElementById('someData');
var clone = document.importNode(template, true);

var linksList = clone.querySelectorAll('img'); // или `a`
linksList.forEach((lnk) => {
  lnk.setAttribute(
    'src', // или href, для`a`
    'https: //ссылка которую надо вставить' + lnk.getAttribute('src') // или href, для`a`
  );
});
document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(clone);
```

Пример кода из файла/адреса сайта, с которого грузим контент:

```
<div id="someData">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- Img is not requested until the <template> goes live. -->
    <img src="/assets/logo.png">
</div>

...
```

Comment: Ага, увидел, примерно понял из комментариев, но так удобнее. Спасибо, сейчас заюзаю )

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно, теперь все так, как мне нужно :-)

Comment: @DenisBubnov всегда пожалуйста, коллега :)